# Truncate table on migration down method of ActiveRecord Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, truncate, rails-migrations

I have the following defined on my `up` method on my migration to set initial data:

```
  def up
    Color.create!({:id=>1,:name=>"",:color=>"FF6633"})
    Color.create!({:id=>2,:name=>"",:color=>"93B233"})
    Color.create!({:id=>3,:name=>"",:color=>"4D90D9"})
    Color.create!({:id=>4,:name=>"",:color=>"C43092"})
  end
```

Is there any `truncate` directive I can put on the `down` method like:

```
def down
   Color.truncate
end
```

Or since I'm setting the IDs on the create should I use only the `destroy_all` method of the model `Color` ?

Answer (score 8):

You can simple use this in your **`up`** method, this will solve your both truncate and id resetting problem also.

```
def up    
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE table_name")  
   Color.create!({:id=>1,:name=>"",:color=>"FF6633"})  
   Color.create!({:id=>2,:name=>"",:color=>"93B233"})  
   Color.create!({:id=>3,:name=>"",:color=>"4D90D9"})  
   Color.create!({:id=>4,:name=>"",:color=>"C43092"})  
end
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't have to pass `:id` into `create!` because ActiveRecord will automatically handle that, thus `:id` likely to get ignored (standard case assumed).

Secondly, it is not a good practice to use ActiveRecord query builder in migration because should the model Color name be changed, you are to have a broken migration. I highly recommend you to use pure SQL and execute that query with `execute()`.

Thirdly, for the `#down` method, you shouldn't truncate the table. You should destroy those 4 colors that you created in `#up`.

Here's how I would write it:

```
def down
  colors = ["FF6633", "93B233", "4D90D9", "C43092"]
  Color.where(:color => colors).destroy_all
end
```

Comment: But how to keep the `id` the same when going back and forth on the migrations? if when `#down` I just `destroy` those 4 colors, when running the migration again ids would be `5,6,7,8` what I need is to keep those `1,2,3,4`.

Comment: couple of things. first off, while it's not a good idea to pass the id, there are cases where you have to do it (conceptually). Coalescing two old tables into one new one, you need the ids unchanged in order to maintain the existing associations. Secondly, you can indeed use ActiveRecord queries to manipulate data inside a migration but you should create dummy versions of the classes that wrap the tables. This will protect you from missing source files but you are limited to the standard models behavior.